# Salesforce lightning:carousel

Tags: salesforce-lightning

I am using the   in the code the Html class name are not viewable.

[image]

but if I use inspect element I can find the HTML class name that it uses such as slds-carousel__content etc.

[image]

My  problem is i cant access those class name on my client side controllers.
Is there a way to get those class name ?

Comment: I am using the lightning:carousel component, in the code the HTML class name are not viewable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to that describes how to change the class. You can get the component by using component.find("insertnamehere").getElement(); It's not always reliable unless you are specifying a render attribute on the controller though.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_show_hide_markup.htm

as a side note: as sanctimonious as some of the mods on the Salesforce stackoverflow might seem, it is still a more likely place to find such content. Good luck.